# Trouble opening text file

Tags: java

I have some trouble reading a file. I have my input.txt in contents package, but the program still can't open the file.

```
String line = null; 
try{
  //loen faili
  FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("contents/input.txt");        
  BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 
     while((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null){
       System.out.println(line);
     }
 buffReader.close();  
 }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
  System.out.println("Error opening file");    
 }catch(IOException ex){
  System.out.println("Error reading file");
 }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to differnetly open files from your app packages than the one from disk, try:

```
InputStream  is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("contents/input.txt");
```